# getting undefined in the console after entering either rock,paper or scissors in the prompt

Tags: javascript, html

```
        <script>


           console.log("enter \game()\ to start the game");


            function computerPlay(){
                let a = ['rock','paper','scissors'];
                let b = a[Math.floor(Math.random * a.length)];
                return b;
            }


            function humanPlay(){
                let c = prompt('rock,paper or scissors');
                return c;
          }


            function playRound ( computerSelection,humanSelection){
                if (computerSelection == humanSelection) {
                    console.log("Its a tie");


                }


               if (computerSelection == 'rock' && humanSelection.toLowerCase() == 'paper') {
                   return 'human wins';

               } 

               else if (computerSelection == 'rock' && humanSelection.toLowerCase() == 'scissors') {
                   return 'computer wins';

               } 

               else if ( computerSelection == 'paper' && humanSelection.toLowerCase() == 'rock') {
                   return 'computer wins';

               } 

               else if (computerSelection == 'paper' && humanSelection.toLowerCase() == 'scissors') {
                   return 'human wins';

               } 

               else if (computerSelection == 'scissors' && humanSelection.toLowerCase() == 'rock') {
                   return 'human wins';

               } 

               else if (computerSelection == 'scissors' && humanSelection.toLowerCase() == 'paper') {
                   return 'computer wins'

               } 

               else if (computerSelection == 'rock' && humanSelection.toLowerCase() == 'scissors') { 
                   return 'computer wins';

               } 

            }
            function game(){
                computerSelection = computerPlay();
                humanSelection = humanPlay();
                let results = playRound(computerSelection,humanSelection);
                console.log(results);



            }






        </script>
```

I've been trying to code this simple game from the Odin project for 2 hours and i can't wrap my head around why isn't the code working. I have looked at a few student solutions and tried to write my code again and again but it just doesn't seem to work each time. what am i doing wrong in this script?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a technical description of a problem. What doesn't work?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: It's a small issue - `Math.random` should be `Math.random()` (inside the `computerPlay()` function)

Comment: @Rob i enter the prompt that is asked for and the output is undefined twice in the console.

Comment: Don't comment. Add that to your question. Otherwise it might be missed and your question will get closed.

Comment: @kira55 LOL, glad to help :) I'm sorry for all the downvotes, I actually upvoted your question

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
let b = a[Math.floor(Math.random * a.length)];
```

It should be:

```
let b = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
```

Also, you can test your code here: https://js.do/

Hope it helps!